# tail -f -catalina.out gives error "cannot open input"

Tags: linux, unix, putty

I'm not able to tail a catalina.out file using tail -f -catalina.out
error shown is tail: cannot open input

logged in as tomcat user. the file has -rw-r--r-- rights. Not sure why  I'm not able to tail it
even after trying --retry.

The file is available, i do not get missing file error. File shows 1.970MiB size. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your command (a starting dash), the correct would be:

```
tail -f catalina.out
```

that assumes you're inside the directory that contains the `catalina.out` file.